# Next.js API function to call AWS Lambda Python function

Tags: aws-lambda, next.js

I need help with a function I'm writing to achieve the following in my Nextjs project:

1. Upload PDF file to client - working
2. Upload PDF to AWS s3 - working
3. Calling an AWS Lambda Python script which takes the s3 file link as query parameter
4. Return data from Python script to state object in Nextjs app

I have already written the Python script and have started writing an API in my Nextjs app which uploads the client-uploaded PDF file to s3. What I'm stuck on now is calling the Lambda Python script URL with the s3 link to the PDF file in the query parameters to call the Lambda Python script. Here is my code but it is not calling the Lambda function:

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  let filepath = "";
  let filename = "";
  const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = new IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      // console.log(fields, files);
      // console.log(files.invoiceFile.filepath);
      filepath = files.invoiceFile.filepath;
      filename = files.invoiceFile.originalFilename;
      console.log(files);
      console.log("This");
      const s3 = new S3.S3({
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
      });
      const params = {
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: filename,
        Body: filepath,
        // Body: base64Data,
        // ContentEncoding: "base64", // required
        contentType: "application/pdf",
      };
      console.log(params);
      const results = s3.upload(params).promise();
      const extractedText = fetch(
        "https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?message=" +
          filename,
        {
          method: "post",
        }
      );
      console.log(extractedText);
      res.status(200).send(results);

      // run(filename, filepath);
    });
  });
};
```

I can call the Lambda Python function successfully when I just paste the URL in the browser to that function is working. Any help would be greatly appreciated